# Asterisk trunk config 'insecure=very'

Tags: voip

I had to add 'insecure=very' configuration to a SIP trunk on my freePBX box for it to register.

Does this configuration open possible threats for my infrastructure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option basically allows  registered hosts to call without re-authenticating. According to [this article](http://kb.smartvox.co.uk/asterisk/secure-asterisk-pbx-part-2/):

> Never include the parameter “insecure=invite” or “insecure=very” when
>   defining a dynamic SIP user account. If you do, it will disable
>   password checking for that account. Where possible, restrict the range
>   of IP addresses from which the user is allowed to connect using the
>   “deny” and “permit” parameters. This is a good idea where all possible
>   source IP addresses are known in advance such as from a local LAN in
>   an office. If possible, avoid setting the type to “friend”. Instead
>   use “type=peer” and “host=dynamic” (see below).